# 100% Height Div with jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create a set of full page DIV's without success on mobile platforms. On iOS and Android devices, the first DIV will show up fine, but the second will have a top-margin even with my margins set to "0".

The red from the first DIV is still visible after scrolling to the bottom.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the JavaScript I used to replicate the problem...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).resize(function() {

        var newHeight = $(window).height();

        $('div').css({
            width: '100%',
            height: newHeight + 'px'
        });

    });

});
```

The CSS...

```
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
        }

        div {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .red {
            background: red;
        }

        .blue {
            background: blue;
        }
```

and HTML...

```
<div class="red">
</div>

<div class="blue">
</div>
```

Comment: Per jQuery docs, you can use `css('height')` to get the same value as `height()`, but including the units, e.g. `px`.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Maybe there's a simpler and different solution

Comment: Works fine in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efytgy3z/)...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use CSS?

```
.red, .blue{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: There will be multiple DIV's and eventually I will be adding sliding functionality and my own personal magic sauce to the slider.

Comment: The number of elements positioned like this can be arbitrary. position:fixed also works really well with sliding panels: http://korynunn.github.io/flap/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by wrapping the DIV's inside a container DIV and setting the overflow-x to hidden.

The new css.

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

div#container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.red {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.blue {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Javascript...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var winHeight = $(window).height(); winWidth = $(window).width();
        $('fp').css(function(){height : winHeight + " !important", width : winWidth + '!important'});
    });
});
```

It works great now in both mobile and desktop browsers.